# Is it possible to have variables visible "only to modules" and its extensions?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following modules, split across multiple files both capable of *extending* `skillet`:

**File1.js:**

```
(function(){
 var privateVar1 = 0;

 var privateFunction1 = function() {
  //function definiton
 };

 skillet.fry() = function() {
  //fry it
  //matchbox.light();
 };

})(window.skillet = window.skillet || {});
```

**File2.js:**

```
(function(){
 var privateVar2 = 0;

 var privateFunction2 = function() {
  //some private function 
 };

 skillet.grillIt = function() {
  //grill It
  //matchbox.strike(); <-- Shared with File1.js
 };

})(window.skillet = window.skillet || {});
```

Is it possible to have a shared variable/object like `matchbox` be sharable by the two modules **without** being bound to `window.matchbox` or `window.skillet.matchbox`? I.e. the *visibility* of `matchbox` should only be to File1.js and File2.js and must not be accessible elsewhere. I doubt if it's possible, but is there a way to achieve such a behavior in JavaScript? If not, what's the best practice to use in this regard?

(It's more like having a shared *event-bus* among a set of related modules without exposing that bus globally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

"private" variables work in JS only because of the scope that the function was declared in.  There is no way to share that scope with a function declared in an entirely different scope.  Scope is an unchangeable property of functions, once they are created.

This is why this sort of thing is usually done with `_foo` style properties.

```
skillet._matchbox = { strike: function() { ... } };
```

The underscore prefix is convention for "internal" and serves as a hint not to mess with it.

---

You could also get creative with how you pass `matchbox` around though, though in all cases it will mean providing a way to get `matchbox` out it's original scope.  Like perhaps, makes a `skillet.extend` method that passes the matchbox to it's argument?

```
(function() {
  var matchbox = { strike: function() { ... } }
  window.skillet = {
    extend: function(fn) {
      fn(matchbox);
    }
  };
})();

skillet.extend(function(matchbox) {
  var privateVar2 = 0;
  var privateFunction2 = function() {};

  skillet.grillIt = function() {
    //grill It
    matchbox.strike();
  };
}
```

Which allows you to use `matchbox` outside it's original scope in a controlled way.  But it also allows anyone to get `matchbox` that maybe shouldn't.

```
var stolenMatchbox;
skillet.extend(function(matchbox) {
  stolenMatchbox = matchbox;
});
while (stolenMatchbox.count > 0) { stolenMatchbox.strike(); }
alert("Now you are outta matches, sucker!");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already dividing your code into multiple files, you may look into using a module loader like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).  You could define a third module for the matchbox and then pass it in as an argument to the two skillets in your example above.  With this approach, you won't have to globally expose the matchbox via the window.

File1.js with require.js would look like this:

```
define(['matchbox'], function(matchbox){
(function(){
    var privateVar1 = 0;

    var privateFunction1 = function() {
     //function definiton
    };

    skillet.fry() = function() {
       //fry it
       matchbox.light();
    };

 })(window.skillet = window.skillet || {});
});
```

matchbox.js would look something like this:

```
define([], function() {
  function light() {
     //light implementation
  }

  function strike() {
     //strike implementation
  }

  return {
     light: light,
     strike: strike
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used requirejs before. Could you please elaborate on what the first two lines mean? And how is the encapsulation achieved?

Comment: Require.js is a javascript module loader that follows the [Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) paradigm](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).  In layman's terms, it's a way to define module dependencies in a #include/import/using type syntax for javascript.

The define() call that I wrapped File1.js in specifies that it depends on the module 'matchbox', which is passed into the function as parameter 'matchbox' once it has completed loading asynchronously.  With this approach, there is no need to register your matchbox module to the global namespace.